# Why are we finding the integrated rate law by starting with r=k[A]?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

When deriving the integrated rate equations, we start off with r =k[A] for example, and then we do the whole integration thing to find an equation of [A] in terms of time. But why are we ingnoring any other reactants here? Wouldnt the r=k[A][B] if B was was another reactant?

Comment: You'd just get a different integrated rate law. Each version of the integrated rate law corresponds to one version of the (non-integrated / differentiated) rate law. The ones with different reactants (like your suggestion of $k[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]$) can get quite tricky to solve, though, which is why those are rarely touched on.

Comment: Note that  r =k[A] and r=k[A][B] assume *elemental reactions.*